# should i create javascript models to map my json to for knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm just getting into knockoutjs and have what is probably a pretty fundamental question.

Is it "best practice" to have a javascript version of my model on the client side to mirrow my server side.

So when I receive say an order object which will have a person object, item object and some properties such as price and so on, is it the norm to then have an order model coded on the client side that I then map my json to?

The ebenfits of that would be intellisense etc but obviously there is also then code duplication.

What is the industry standard for handling this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no industry standard.

I prefer to serialize my object into json and use knockout.mapping for making observable with them

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

You don't have intellisense but in the other hand you don't have code duplication

Comment: I do the same thing. Javascript intellisense is only barely functional anyways, so not a huge loss ;).

Answer (score 1):

Key feature of knockout is bindings, for bidirectional binding (update UI after model changed)  you should use [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#observables) properties. It isn't critical are observable properties part of model or viewmodel or anything else. Also you can use mapping plugin for direct generation viewmodel from JSON. This plugin make all properties observable. But this is not useful for models with methods and inner properties.